# Array and Json error

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

So I have a JSON file with this in it:

```
{ "accounts":{
    {
        "ID":"0",
        "steamID":"xxx",
        "balance": 54
    },
    {
        "ID":"1",
        "steamID":"xxx",
        "balance": 522
    }
}
```

Yet whenever I try to run it:

```
Error when getting config: SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 1319
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean `"accounts": [`…`]`? Looks like you’re trying to make an array but with `{`…`}` which is the wrong syntax for that.

Comment: There also should be another '}' in the end

Comment: `{{` is not valid JSON syntax

Comment: So I should add [ instead of { at the start and a } at the end?

Comment: Works perfect. Although, how would I connect with it?

config.accounts.steamID[1] ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "JSON file" or "run it". A file is a physical collection of bytes stored on a disk somewhere. If that's really what you have, you need to read it in somehow. Then, you don't "run" it, but rather "parse" it. In any case it must be valid JSON. You can try running it through a JSON validator to check that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you try to set object {} as parameter of parent object, it is incorrect. You have to name inner objects like that:

```
 { "accounts":{
     "sampA":{
       "ID":"0",
       "steamID":"xxx",
       "balance": 54
    },
    "sampB":{
       "ID":"1",
       "steamID":"xxx",
       "balance": 522
    }
}}
//accounts.sampA.steamID
//accounts.sampB.ID
```

or change "account" value from object {} to array []:

```
 { "accounts":[
     {
       "ID":"0",
       "steamID":"xxx",
       "balance": 54
     },
     {
       "ID":"1",
       "steamID":"xxx",
       "balance": 522
     }
]}
//accounts[0].ID
//accounts[1].balance
```

Answer (score 0):

The json seems to be incorrect.

There is no closing braces & there is an unbalanced `{`

```
{ "accounts":{
    {
    "ID":"0",
    "steamID":"xxx",
    "balance": 54
    },
    {
    "ID":"1",
    "steamID":"xxx",
    "balance": 522
    }
}
```

Secondly there are two succeeding `{` `{` after `accounts` which is wrong.

A json array look like this

```
var sampleArray =[{contain object property},{contain object property}..]
```